# Does BIOS device whitelist affect Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, laptop, hardware, thinkpad

Starting with 2002, Lenovo (actually, it was IBM back then) started [whitelisting the wireless adapters](http://www.thinkpads.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=737952#p737952) and other devices allowed to be used in their ThinkPad laptops. Some other manufacturers are probably doing this, too. The exact list of allowed hardware was never publicly documented.

Some enthusiasts have modified BIOS to remove these restrictions.

Are such modifications necessary if I'm only going to run Ubuntu on my laptop? (not Windows).

Is the answer any different if I'm only going to run Windows in a virtual machine of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIOS whitelists are OS independent.A VM will not change that as it just uses the BIOS you have.